# Unformatting LaTeX code with Emacs & AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, formatting, latex, auctex

Emacs + AUCTeX provides all sort of commands for formatting text, but I can't find a way to "unformat" a snippet of code (unless undoing the change right after having run a formatting command).
For example, suppose you have the following snippet with LaTeX formatting

```
foo \whatever{bar} quux
```

I'd like to remove the `\whatever{}` wrapper by selecting the relevant text, or by placing the cursor at its beginning/end, and using a key combination to get

```
foo bar quux
```